# How to assert all items in a collection using fluent-assertions?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, collections, fluent-assertions

Say I want to test a method returning a bunch of items of the following type using [fluent-assertions](https://github.com/dennisdoomen/fluentassertions/) to ensure that all items have their `IsActive`-flag set to `true`:

```
public class Item
{
    public bool IsActive { get; set; }
}
```

To achieve that I could simply iterate over the collection and assert every item separately in a foreach-loop:

```
var items = CreateABunchOfActiveItems();
foreach (var item in items)
{
    item.IsActive.Should().BeTrue("because I said so!");
}
```

But is there a more fluent way to assert every item in the whole collection at once?

Answer (score 64, accepted):

The recommended way is to use `OnlyContain`:

```
items.Should().OnlyContain(x => x.IsActive, "because I said so!");
```

These will also work:

```
items.All(x => x.IsActive).Should().BeTrue("because I said so!");

items.Select(x => x.IsActive.Should().BeTrue("because I said so!"))
     .All(x => true);
```

Note that the last line (`.All(x => true)`) forces the previous `Select` to execute for each item.

Comment: It worths mentioning that these two options are not equivalent: ```.OnlyContain``` requires collection to be not empty, while ```.All().Should().BeTrue()``` - does not.

Answer (score 6):

Something like replacing your foreach loop with a foreach method should do the trick (at least a little bit).

```
var items = CreateABunchOfActiveItems();
items.ForEach(item => item.IsActive.Should().BeTrue("because I said so, too!"));
```

I find this syntax a little bit more fluent than traditional foreach loop :)

ForEach method is not defined if your method `CreateABunchOfActiveItems` returns an IEnumerable. But it can be easily implemented as an extension method:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> ForEach<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumeration, 
    Action<T> action)
{
    // I use ToList() to force a copy, otherwise your action 
    // coud affect your original collection of items!. If you are confortable 
    // with that, you can ommit it
    foreach (T item in enumeration.ToList())
    {
        action(item);
        yield return item;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is also a valid approach - And there are libraries providing the `ForEach`-extension. But I was mainly looking if there is a way to do this kind of natively with the fluent-assertion library.

Comment: And also note, that `ToList()` already enumerates the original collection, which then gets enumerated once again by the `foreach`-loop...

Comment: Yes, I'm aware that it may not be the best approach when dealing with heavy operations (many items, db connections, filereading, etc.) but it suits me for my daily testing.

Answer (score 5):

Use `AllSatisfy()`, which was added in v. 6.5.0 as per https://fluentassertions.com/collections/.

In your case, it would be:

```
var items = CreateABunchOfActiveItems();
items.Should().AllSatisfy(
    i => i.IsActive.Should().BeTrue("because I said so!")
);
```