# Compare a collection's item (like a DateTimeOffset) with FluentAssertions' Contain more specifically with Should

Tags: unit-testing, datetime, testing, nunit, fluent-assertions

I "just" want to parse and compare a `DateTime(Offset)` from a string and check whether it is in a List of collections with [*FluentAssertions*](https://fluentmigrator.github.io/). [`.Should()`](https://fluentassertions.com/collections/) is easy enough to use for comparing whether there is an element of that type.
However, as I am comparing times I *also* want to [`.BeCloseTo`  with an offset](https://fluentassertions.com/datetimespans/) as the time may not be *that* accurate and I don't care how accurate it is.

`CronExpressions` comntains a `Raw` property that represents the string as a DateTime(Offset). (And even if not, let's just assume it does. A test failure would tell me.)

```cs
        [Test]
        public void SchedulesItselfForNow()
        {
            this.job = new Job();

            this.job.MetaData.CronExpressions.Should().Contain(x =>
                DateTimeOffset.Parse(x.Raw).Should().BeCloseTo(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1))
            );
        }
```

I already asked *ChatGPT* and the only solution it presented to me, was this as a slight refactoring:

```cs
        [Test]
        public void SchedulesItselfForNow()
        {
            this.job = new Job();

            this.job.MetaData.CronExpressions
                .Select(x => DateTimeOffset.Parse(x.Raw))
                .Should()
                .Contain(date => date.Should().BeCloseTo(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
        }
```

### Idea

I know I can use `.Which`, but for that I have to have a working (usual boolean) assertion/comparison before. In my case, I don't have this, I just want to compare the string directly:

```cs
        [Test]
        public void SchedulesItselfForNow()
        {
            this.job = new Job();

            this.job.MetaData.CronExpressions
                .Select(x => DateTimeOffset.Parse(x.Raw))
                .Should()
                .Contain(date => true) // but what to use here?
                .Which.Should().BeCloseTo(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1));
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Ah, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76688490/15488899) lead me to the `...Satisfy` methods, and this seems to do what i want:

```cs
        [Test]
        public void SchedulesItselfForNow()
        {
            this.job = new Job();

            this.job.MetaData.CronExpressions
                .Select(x => DateTimeOffset.Parse(x.Raw))
                .Should()
                .SatisfyRespectively(x => x.Should().BeCloseTo(DateTimeOffset.Now, TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1)));
        }
```